# SQL: Reusing Query with EXIST

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

Ok so I have a query that looks something like

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT NULL 
                    FROM B 
                    WHERE B.LENGTH = A.LENGTH + 10) 
         THEN 'Yes'
         ELSE 'No'
   END AS Result1,
   CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                    FROM B 
                    WHERE B.LENGTH = A.LENGTH - 10) 
         THEN 'Yes'
         ELSE 'No'
   END AS Result2,
   CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT NULL 
                    FROM B 
                    WHERE B.LENGTH = A.LENGTH) 
         THEN 'Yes'
         ELSE 'No'
   END AS Result3
FROM A
```

As you can see the 3 EXIST Queries are almost the same with little differentce that (I hope) can be passed as an argument.

I tried to create a TVF but it fails when I Return `SELECT NULL...` but works if I use `SELECT *`. The thing I am afraid of is that I don't need the values I want to check if only exists and that's it.

**My question is what would be the best way to refactor this code so it's not that repetitive?**

Comment: Hello! Add the code to produce a working example and we can try and refactor it.

Comment: Putting that in a function will likely kill the performance. So I'd rather leave it as it is. Besides adding the commas after the first two column expressions that you miss... ;)

Comment: Thanks for that! The thing is that the Query inside the exist is not that small and looks really ugly BUT if it'd kill the performance I agree with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to generate one query per row having three columns:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CA.C1 > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
     , CASE WHEN CA.C2 > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
     , CASE WHEN CA.C3 > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
FROM A
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN B.LENGTH = A.LENGTH + 10 THEN 1 END)
         , COUNT(CASE WHEN B.LENGTH = A.LENGTH - 10 THEN 1 END)
         , COUNT(CASE WHEN B.LENGTH = A.LENGTH      THEN 1 END)
    FROM B
    WHERE B.LENGTH IN (A.LENGTH + 10, A.LENGTH - 10, A.LENGTH)
) AS CA(C1, C2, C3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT A.Length,
       CASE COUNT(CASE A.[LENGTH] WHEN B.[LENGTH] - 10 THEN 1 END)WHEN 0 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS result1,
       CASE COUNT(CASE A.[LENGTH] WHEN B.[LENGTH] + 10 THEN 1 END)WHEN 0 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS result2,
       CASE COUNT(CASE A.[LENGTH] WHEN B.[LENGTH] THEN 1 END)WHEN 0 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS result3
FROM A
     CROSS JOIN B
GROUP BY A.Length;
```

This saves on 3 scans of the table `B`, but you will still need repetitive logic of some kind.

Comment: A join condition of `B.LENGTH IN (A.LENGTH, A.LENGTH + 10, A.LENGTH - 10)` could potentially be much more efficient than a `CROSS JOIN `